# Does HTML5 require an action attribute for forms?

Tags: forms, html, w3c-validation

I've just run a webpage of mine through the W3C HTML5 validator, and it validates completely, even though the form in it doesn't have an `action` attribute, which the HTML 4 validator always complains about. Considering the fact that the HTML5 validator is still experimental, is the fact that the form validating despite not having an `action` attribute a problem with the validator, or has the HTML5 spec changed to not require that attribute any more?

Answer (score 14):

According to the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-fs-action) `action` is not mandatory:

*The action and formaction content attributes, **if specified**, must have a value that is a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces.*

Although, section *4.10.1.3 Configuring a form to communicate with a server* states that:

*You also have to specify the URL of the service that will handle the submitted data, using the action attribute.*

So, the specification says that if you want your form to communicate with a server it shall provide the `action` attribute. Which, in my opinion, is not the only truth as you can specify `action`s on buttons as well.

EDIT: I must admit that I can't finally answer your question with **Yes** or **No**...

Comment: You are correct. The `action` attribute is not mandatory. Note that the section 4.10.1.3 is marked *non-normative*, that is, the text is guidance, and does not itself impose any requirements. So your first quote is the relevant one. Good answer. +1

Comment: Is 'specifiction' a deliberate misspelling? ;)