# Why does the url change when a self referencing form is submitted

Tags: php, forms

I am submitting a form on the url `http://example.com/test.php` and this form references itself so the url should stay when the form is submitted the same. Except when the form is submitted, the url becomes `example.com/test.php/test.php` 
How does my php file become a folder for another php file?? I checked my files and I do not have any folders called `test.php`.

Thanks to anyone that can help

Comment: possible useful answers in this question: [14093316/why-use-serverphp-self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093316/why-use-serverphp-self-instead-of)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Or better yet...

```
   <form action="<?php $_SERVER['php_self']; ?>" method="post">
```

.....

```
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the action as

```
action=""
```

I believe that the form will now post to itself.

Additionally, you could use an absolute url in your action. It would be helpful to see what the action being generated in the HTML is and what PHP (if any) you are using to generate the form with