# Calling PHP code within same php file

Tags: php, html

I want to create a form that calls PHP code within the same php file on submit.

Reading this, [Why use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] instead of ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093316/why-use-serverphp-self-instead-of), it seems I can use `action=""` instead of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` to do this.

If that's so, when I click submit, why isn't this PHP code at the top of the file executed?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "submitted";
}
```

It should say `submitted` on the page.

In Google DevTools, the `network` tab doesn't show that the file is being called, just that the page is reloaded.

Form snippet:

```
<div id="contactForm">  
        <form role="form" action="" method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
                         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                   </div>
               </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
         </form>
```

Comment: Show the form that is submitted

Comment: Heya. Are you sure $_POST['Submit'] is set? Try var_dump($_POST['Submit']).. or check if you used a lowercase 'submit' in the HTML code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says type="submit", not name="submit"..

Comment: Ah this fixed it. Why does it not recognize the type?

Comment: Well, type tells the browser what it's for while (variable) name is used by PHP (in combination with value). So in this case, use both attributes.. or select a method from one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no variable in your form named "submit".

If you just want to test if the form has been submitted, you can use this:

```
if($_POST) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `if(isset($_POST))` (else you will get PHP notices) and try to change your action from `""` to `"#"`, also add the `name="submit"` attribute to your submit button.