# Why do content disappear out of table when it's updated

Tags: php, mysqli

I have build a back end system that update text and images. Values will be passed from a URL on an admin.php page to the index page. A table is being used to display the text and image. The updated text and image should be displayed in the table. For some strange reason, the text and image always disappear when I update content and then click on the edit content button. The content is updating in database with no problem . I am not geting any errors. How do I get updated text and image to display in the table without content disappearing? I thank you for your help, I am still learning PHP. [image: Edit content]  [image: Content removed out of table]

This is the code:

admin.php

```
<?php
  require_once('authorize.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Remove Thumbnail Administration</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Administration</h2>
  <p>Below is a list of all thumbnails. Use this page to remove thumbnails as needed.</p>
  <hr />

<?php
  require_once('appvars.php');
  require_once('connectvars.php');

  // Connect to the database 
  $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  // Retrieve the data from MySQL
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY name ASC, caption ASC";
  //$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY name DESC, caption ASC";     
  $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 /// Loop through the array of data, formatting it as HTML 
  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Caption</th><th>Action</th></tr>';
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
    // Display the thumbnails data
    echo '<tr class="scorerow"><td><strong>' . $row['name'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['caption'] . '</td>';

    //edit link

      echo '<td><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&amp;image=' . $row['image1'] . '&amp;name=' . $row['name'] . 
    '&amp;caption=' . $row['caption'] .
      '&amp;video=' . $row['video'] . '">Edit </a>'; 




    echo '</td></tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';   
  echo "<br><br>";

  mysqli_close($conn);
?>

</body> 
</html>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Edit Conent</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <style>
      .bigger_textbox {
   width: 400px;
   height: 40px;
 }

     </style> 

</head>
<body>
  <h3>Edit Conent</h3>

<?php
  require_once('appvars.php');
  require_once('connectvars.php');

  $vid="";
  $vname="";
  $vcaption="";
  $vvideo="";
  $id ="";

  // Connect to the database
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  if(isset($_POST["button_edit"])){
     $id = $_POST["id"];
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $caption = $_POST['caption']; 
    $video = $_POST['video'];

     $old_picture = $_POST['old_picture'];
     if(!empty($_FILES["new_picture"]["name"])) {
    $new_picture = $_FILES["new_picture"]["name"];
    $qry = mysqli_query($dbc,"Update table1 Set image1='$new_picture', name='$name', caption='$caption', video='$video' Where id='$id'");

        $target_dir = "images/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["new_picture"]["name"]);
       $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["new_picture"]["tmp_name"],$target_file)){
    if (isset($old_picture) && ($old_picture != $new_picture)) {
              @unlink("images/" . $old_picture);
              echo "<h1>image was uploaded</h1>";

     }
     }
    }
    else{
 $qry = "Update table1 Set name='$name', caption='$caption', video='$video' Where id='$id'";
}

$qryUpdate = mysqli_query($dbc,$qry);
    }

else if(isset($_GET["edit"])){
    $qry = mysqli_query($dbc,"Select * From table1 Where id='".$_GET["edit"]."'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $vid=$row["id"];
        $old_picture=$row["image1"];
        $vname=$row["name"];
        $vcaption=$row["caption"];
        $vvideo=$row["video"];


    }
}


?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table>
    <tr>
            <td>Product ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $vid;?>"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="name" value="<?php echo $vname;?>"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Caption</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="caption"  value="<?php echo $vcaption;?>"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Video</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="video"  value="<?php echo $vvideo;?>"></td></tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="old_picture" value="<?php if (!empty($old_picture)) echo $old_picture; ?>" />
        <tr><td>Picture</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="new_picture" ></td></tr>
        <?php if (!empty($old_picture)) {
        echo '<img class="profile" src="images/' . $old_picture . '" alt="image" style=width:150px;height:xpx;">';
      } 
      ?>
        <tr><td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="button_edit" value="Edit Content"></td></tr> </table>
</form>
<table border=1>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Caption</th>
    <th>Video</th><th>image</th>  <th>Action</th></tr>
    <?php
     if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $qry =mysqli_query($dbc, "Select * From table1 Where id='".$_GET["id"]."'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$row["name"].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["caption"].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["video"].'</td>'; 
        echo '<td><img src="images/'.$row["image1"].'" style=width:100px;height:xpx;"/></td>'; 

        echo '<td><a href="?id='.$row["id"].'&edit='.$row["id"]. '&video='.$row["video"].'&image='.$row["image1"].'">Edit</a> </td></tr>';
        }


    }



    ?>
</table>

<p><a href="admin.php">&lt;&lt; Back to admin page</a></p>

<br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];` does not include url variables, so your `$_GET["id"]` will be blank on form post. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14093316/689579. Simple fix will be to just do `<form action="" method="post" ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of the index.php you're clearing the values of the variables.

try this instead:

```
<?php 
    isset($vid) ? $vid : "";
    isset($vname) ? $vname : "";
    isset($vcaption) ? $vcaption : "";
    isset($vvideo) ? $vvideo : "";
    isset($id) ? $id : "";
```

This is a quick response; however, you need to reorganize your code.
Separate the HTML parts into partials, where the static parts (header and footer can be included in a single line).  also, instead of using echo on every line, use $output .= "resulted data"; to concatenate the data, then echo the $output.